# Validar campo numero / numero maximo caracteres JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente validación:

```
-consumo: número decimal o entero (por ej: 10.5, 8, 16, 9.5, etc.)
```

¿Por qué me falla?

Os pongo el código:

```
public class Validaciones {
    public static boolean validarFecha(String fecha){
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
        //setLenient no permite modificar la fecha a una posible válida.
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        try {
            Date d= sdf.parse(fecha);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Validaciones.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static boolean validarMatricula(String matricula){
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[\\d]{4}[A-Z]{3}$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(matricula);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean validarBastidor(String bastidor){
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[A-Z0-9]{15}$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(bastidor);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static boolean validarConsumo(double consumo){
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+([,\\.][0-9]*)?$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(consumo);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Index.java

```
        if(Validaciones.validarFecha("29-02-2020"))
            System.out.println("Fecha valida");
        else
            System.out.println("Fecha NO valida");


        if(Validaciones.validarMatricula("2593HBD"))
            System.out.println("Matricula valida");
        else
            System.out.println("Matricula NO valida");

        if(Validaciones.validarBastidor("AAA456789ABCDEF"))
            System.out.println("Bastidor valido");
        else
            System.out.println("Bastidor NO valido");

        if(Validaciones.validarConsumo(10.5))
            System.out.println("Consumo valido");
        else
            System.out.println("Consumo NO valido");
```

Comment: ¿Qué falla? ¿Qué resultado obtienes?

Comment: Matcher mat = pat.matcher(consumo); --> double cannot to be converted to CharSequence

Comment: Pero si `consumo` ya es de tipo `double` (que, de paso, es la razón del error), no hay necesidad de validarlo. Ya sabes que es un número por su tipo. ¿Tal vez la intención era que el tipo del parámetro `consumo` fuera `String`?

Comment: ¿si cierto es, la intención es que fuera String y luego comprobarlo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supongo que lo leer de un textBox los datos o de algún método de entrada. Así que deberías pasarle un String a la validación ya que seguramente te están llegando así y las expresiones regulares evalúan cadenas de caracteres, por ejemplo:

```
  if(Validaciones.validarConsumo("10.A")) //Consumo no valido
  if(Validaciones.validarConsumo("10.5")) //Consumo  valido
```

Y implementar la función pasandole un String también

```
 public static boolean validarConsumo(String consumo){
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+([,\\.][0-9]*)?$");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(consumo);
        if (mat.matches()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```